# Summing-up For an Arbitrary List of Rows

Tags: mysql, sqlite, duplicates

I wish I could write something like this:

```
SELECT sum(weight) FROM items WHERE itemID IN (4217,4575,6549,4217)
```

where `itemID` is the primary key, and SQLite and MySQL would process it as expected, i.e. add the 4217-th row to the sum twice, but they don't.

is there something at least in MySQL I'm not aware of that's intended for cases like this? if not, what would a workaround be like? any row can have any number of duplicates in the list. the list can be big although in most cases is small.

Comment: The question is unclear. If you have two (or ten, or a gazilion) items with `itemID=4217` their weights would be summed, regardless of how many times it appears in the `in` clause. Can you share some sample data, the result you expect and the actual result you're getting?

Comment: itemID is the primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any out of the box functionality that can do this. Here is the workaroud. You can insert those values into temp table and use a join:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE List(ID INT);
INSERT INTO List(ID) VALUES(4217),(4575),(6549),(4217);

SELECT SUM(i.weight) 
FROM items i
JOIN List l ON i.itemID = l.ID;
```

Comment: yes, i also thought about it. but isn't it strange that we have to create another table to get the sum while all the data is already there? nevertheless, i will accept your answer if nobody comes up with a better solution. thank you.

Comment: Well I am not sure about MySQL, but in SQL Server you can do this with inline generation of table like : 

`SELECT SUM(i.weight) 
FROM Items i
JOIN (values(1),(2)) l(ID) ON i.ID = l.ID`